# Heroku database does not respond using psql

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, heroku-postgres

I am using psql to work with Heroku database. I am able to create tables, add columns and insert values, however when I am trying to alter column name or data type I have no response.

```
  Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |               Default               
----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('reviews_id_seq'::regclass)
 book_id  | integer                  |           | not null | 
 user_id  | integer                  |           | not null | 
 review   | character varying(10000) |           | not null | 
 comments | character varying(1000)  |           |          | 
 score    | integer 

=> ALTER TABLE reviews ALTER COLUMN book_id SET DATA TYPE integer;
^CCancel request sent
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
=> ALTER TABLE reviews ALTER COLUMN book_id TYPE integer;
```

Does anybody have an idea what can go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably waiting for a lock, but you have other sessions/transactions that are using that table or even have pending open transactions on it. Run the ALTER TABLE again, then connect a second time and check `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: Building on what a_horse_with_no_name says, you can check for these directly through the Heroku CLI by running `pg:locks` and `pg:blocking`.

Comment: Thanks for advises, however the problems have disappeared and the only thing that changed, is the place from which I am connected to the Internet.
Anyway I tried to write those commands 
(pg_stat_activity, pg:locks  and pg:blocking) in postgres run in terminal and via heroku CLI, but it was not understood.
Is there some other way I should type those commands?